# Using JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT alongside @XmlElement(nillable = true)

Tags: json, xml, object, jackson, jackson-databind

I am new to the Jackson annotations and trying to map a JSON to an object. In the JSON file, I have added null values, invalid values as well as missing values to make some test data.

For example, there is a field named 'Name'.

```
private String name;
```

Using my JSON file, various values can be assigned to it.

ex-: `"name": "Xavior"`
or `"name": " "`
or `"name": null`
or the "name" field is missing.

With the use of the `JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT` annotation, I am able to ignore the name field whenever a value is not assigned to it. However, if it's assigned as null in the JSON file, those also get ignored while deserializing. What I want is to take the name field as null (`name = null`), but what actually happens is it gets ignored.

The summary is, I **want to ignore empty or absent values** but **not null values**.

I have tried to make both ends meet by using @XmlElement(nillable = true) annotation, but it does not work. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: 1. How is `@XmlElement` related to JSON? 2. Your problem/scenario is not clear. Please explain: what exactly you are doing? de-/serialization?, How? "expected vs output"?

Comment: @xerx593 So what I'm trying to do is deserialize the JSON to the animal object. I want to use the data in the JSON file to create several instances of the animal object. So here, I am using JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT annotation to ignore missing values. The missing values are successfully ignored. However, it also ignores the null values as well. But what I really want is for those fields to be assigned as null.

Comment: you cannot have an "Animal" (as shown) without "color" (field...in java), the best you can have: map it to another (colorless) animal (class), or live with the `null`)

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting, thankyou you anyways for trying. :) I'll look into another solution.

Comment: sorry: or the color-less animals (finer object structure), or the `null` ...or you can convert the json to a `Map<String, Object>` which approximates/depicts json *best*, due to it's "dynamic structure" for the sake of "type-safety" , "accessors" and "static structure"